# Python: Pandas: Groupby & Pivot Tables are missing rows

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe composed of individuals (their ID's in), activities, and corresponding scores. I'm trying to get the sum of the scores when grouping by the student and an activity type. I can do this with the following:

```
data_detail.pivot_table(["total_scored","total_scored_omitted"], index = ["id","activity"], aggfunc="sum")

data_detail.groupby(["id","activity"]).sum()
```

However, when I check the results by looking at a typical student:

```
data_detail[data_detail["id"]== 41824840].sort_values("activity")
```

I see that there are some activities listed for that given student which are missing from the groupby/pivot table. How can I ensure the final groupby/pivot table is complete and isn't missing any values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ***data type* for the scores wasn't consistent (and a float at that!).**

Some of them were strings. After I converted all of the scores into floats, the missing activities showed up.

As an added benefit, having the datatypes be uniform, made the calculation much faster!